# IOS posting a photo on facebook with suggested text

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

Can I share a photo on facebook from an IPhone app and include a "suggested text" (default description).

`presentShareDialogWithPhotoParams` only has photos to include
`presentShareDialogWithLink` needs to be an actual link...
(I have a URL of the image on my server, but it is not a nice link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot include any text for the message part of the post. Doing so would be against section 2.3 of the Platform Policy (https://developers.facebook.com/policy/)